# What parameters to use to call an unmanaged DLL in powershell (call ok in C program)

Tags: c, powershell, dll

I've the mydll.dll (unmanaged, no manifest) contains myfun (6 parameters). Some years ago, I've created C program to call it, it's working. Today, I need to call mydll.dll without EXE. I've found in stackoverflow how to do it with Powershell, but when I call myfun there are error about parameters.
Could you help me to have the right syntax to call myfun ?

C program which is working :

```
typedef int __cdecl (*GLIX)(LPSTR xa, LPINT xalen, LPSTR xb, LPINT xblen, LPSTR xc, LPINT xclen);
char a[256], b[256], c[256];
int alen = 255, blen = 255, clen = 255;
char * mydll;
struct stat s; if (stat(mydll, &s) != 0) return 1; // no mydll
HMODULE hm = LoadLibrary(TEXT(mydll); if (hm == NULL) return 2; // mydll not loaded
GLIX myfun = (GLIX)GetProcAddress(hm, "myfun"); if (myfun == NULL) return 3; // myfun not found
if (myfun(a, &alen, b, &blen, c, &clen) != 0) return 4; // call myfun
```

My test in Powershell :

```
# test.ps1
param()
$signature = @'
[DllImport("mydll.dll")]
public static extern uint myfun(string xa, int xalen, string xb, int xblen, string xc, int xclen);
'@
$type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name mydll -Namespace myfun -PassThru
$a = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder 256; [int]$alen = 255;
$b = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder 256; [int]$blen = 255;
$c = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder 256; [int]$clen = 255;
$type::myfun($a, [ref]$alen, $b, [ref]$blen, $c, [ref]$clen)
write-host 'a = ' $a.tostring()
write-host 'b = ' $b.tostring()
write-host 'c = ' $c.tostring()
```

The error :

```
    PS C:\XXX> .\test.ps1
    Impossible de convertir l'argument «alen» (valeur «System.Management.Automation.PSReference`1[System.Int32]») de «myfun» en type «System.Int32»: «Impossible de convertir la valeur «
    System.Management.Automation.PSReference`1[System.Int32]» du type «
    System.Management.Automation.PSReference`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]» en type «System.Int32».»
    Au caractère C:\XXX\test.ps1:11 : 1
     $type::myfun($a, [ref]$alen, $b, [ref]$blen, $c, [ref]$clen ...
     CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

I understand the trouble is about integer parameters but I don't know how to declare and use them right. Thank for your help. Sorry for any mistake, it's my first post here.Jean-Claude

Comment: Sorry for the begin, I don't understand why my "hello" disappears.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `[ref]` keywords? You might find that the .NET CLR can marshal the values just fine without it...

Comment: Since the parameters in the dllimported function aren't marked as "out" in the definition the [ref] is not going to work.

Comment: Without [ref] : exception during call, try to load program with bad format.

Comment: If I mark all parameters with "out" like that :: Exception lors de l'appel de "myfun" avec "6" argument(s): «Tentative de chargement d’un programme de format
incorrect. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x8007000B)»

Comment: Sorry, validate to fast : with all parameters "out", message to use "ref" for all parameters. So I add [ref] for all parameters, then error "try to load program with bad format". I'm lost.